# Как реализовать дистанционную отправку форм?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, node.js, веб-программирование

Всем привет!

Подскажите куда копать, что читать? Задача в следующем. Есть на сайте виртуальная комната с формой(страница сайта с доступом), несколько авторизованных пользователей находятся в этой комнате, в этой комнате есть форма С несколькими полями для каждого пользователя. Как можно сделать так, чтобы админ нажимал кнопку, и все формы от каждого пользователя отсылались из комнаты админу.

Comment: У вас сайт на ноде?почитайте про сокеты

Comment: Ну смотря на чем у вас сайт, какова реализация и какие инструменты используете, но могу посоветовать Меркурий, думаю то, что вам нужно: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/mercure.html

Comment: А в принципе, можете долбиться в опр. url, парсить формы, создавать их и тем же curl-ом отправить в обработчик. Никто вам не мешает так сделать. Чтобы было проще, создайте компонент-селектор форм на js-jQuery, потом форму на бэк и далее в нужный обработчик.

Comment: @Ravshan, Borislav Товарищи, спасибо за советы и линки, ушел читать/изучать! благодарю вас, что не прошли мимо.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу пару вариантов реализации данной задачи.

Вы можете написать дополнительно сервер на сокетах, либо хранить экземпляры форм пользователей на сервере и при  изменении формы отправлять get или post запрос на сервер с данными формы, когда админ захочет получить результат он отправит запрос на сервер и получит ответ с сервера без опрашивания всех пользователей... это + так как связь на сокетах нужно держать постоянно а get и post запросы нагружают сервер только в момент обработки.